# Call Html.BeginForm asynchronously

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, callback

In ASP.NET MVC 3 application I'm trying to upload the file using Html.BeginForm helper, like :

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("ImportFile", "Home", new { someId = Id }, FormMethod.Post, new { enctype="multipart/form-data" } )) %>
```

From ImportFile action during the upload I need to return status code (say "Success" or "Failed") and show an appropriate alert on UI. One way is to call form Action asynchronously and from JS check the status code code each 2 seconds say. 
How can I call that asynchronously? Or is there any other way to implement this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Bear in mind there're limitations on the HTTP protocol to peek into the process of a file upload. Assuming your ImportFile helper can disclose such information, and that it can be accessed via a RESTful service, say, importstatus.aspx, here's how you can pull its status:

```
var statuschecker=setInterval(){
    var rq=xmlHTTPRequestObject();
    rq.open('GET','importstatus.aspx',true);
    rq.onreadystatechange=function(){
      if (rq.readyState==4&&rq.status==200){
        if (rq.responseText=='2'){
          clearInterval(statuschecker); //stop the updater
          statuschecker=null; //prevent memory leak
          return;
        }

        if (rq.responseText=='1'){
          //display that it's still being uploaded
        }
      }//xhr status
    }

    rq.send(null);
}, 1000); //poll every second
```

In your web service, return 2 when the process is terminated. The call back function should terminate the watcher interval/timer when the term signal is received.